# User to user email for Drupal site

Tags: drupal

I would like to allow users of my Drupal site to send anonymous email to each other but have not found a module that does this. Coding is likely not an option for me for this issue as I'm both new to Drupal and don't know PHP.
Does anyone know if there is a module to help with this?
If there are no modules then code I will. Any example code or recommended learning resources would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your server shall provide the email accounts? Or do you mean a private message system (not necessarily using SMTP)? And what do you mean by "anonymous"?

Comment: By anonymous I meant that the users cannot see each other's email addresses. As for the technology behind sending the messages I was hoping Drupal would take care of that. I'm far off my turf here as a C# desktop developer who is new to web and Drupal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could something like [this](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/privatemsg) work? It is a private messaging addon, allowing users to communicate on the site, it also provides users with the option "notify-by-email". Assuming i understood your question. Anonymous as in not able to see each others e-mail.

Comment: This sounds like what I need as I was also looking to have a record of the interaction between users and I'm going to dig into it deeper. My main concern is how the user will chose to have the email sent. I read they have to go edit their profile. Knowing my user base, some of who will be senior execs with little patients, they would be unlikely to go edit their profile, won't get the email and that would be a showstopper for the whole purpose of the site.

Comment: I't should be fairly easy to edit this property to fit your needs. For example auto-check the "notify-on-new-message" property. That way you will auto-force notifications on new messages.